# How can I use c syscall wrapper?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I try to create a smaller version of hello world.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<unistd.h>

void _start()
{
  syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Hello, World!\n", 14);
  syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
```

This code is working, if I try to do `gcc -Wall -g -s -O3 hworld.c -o hello7 -nostartfiles`. I want to get a smaller version of hello world. So, I try to use `-nostdlib`. It's not working, if I try use  `gcc -Wall -Os -nostdlib -o hello7  hworld.c` it gives me errors.

```
hworld.c: In function ‘_start’:
hworld.c:7:11: error: ‘SYS_write’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Hello, World!\n", 14);
       ^
hworld.c:7:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
hworld.c:8:11: error: ‘SYS_exit’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   syscall(SYS_exit, 0);

I try to use #include<sys/syscall.h> It gives me other errors.

hworld.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `syscall'
hworld.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `syscall'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I learned I need to use syscall wrapper. It called `libc.a`. It locates at `/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/lib64/libc.a`
How can I use this wrapper to resolve the error? Please help me.

Comment: I think you want `-static` and not `-nostdlib`...

Comment: @zwol He needs to link implementation of `syscall(2)` so `-nostdlib` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine on RHEL 6.10:

```
$ cat tmp.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
void _start() {
  syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Hello, World!\n", 14);
  syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
$ gcc tmp.c -nostartfiles
$ ./a.out
Hello, World!
```